# Importing pywinauto (or comtypes) clobbers existing COM object

Tags: python, win32com, pywinauto, comtypes, pythoncom

Creating / getting a COM object using `win32com.client.GetActiveObject` and then `import pywintypes` results in an `AttributeError` upon each call to the original COM object.

#### Code to reproduce

```
import win32com.client
catia_com = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('CATIA.Application')

# then later when needed, do some pywinauto stuff
import pywinauto.application

# back to working directly on catia com object
print(catia.caption)  # raises Attribute error from within win32com.client
```

Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this which I'd like to share, but I'd also like to hear feedback on my understanding and what is the appropriate dependency where this should be addressed to prevent others from having same issue.

## Solution

Add `import comtypes` before calling `win32com.client`.

#### Example

```
import comtypes
import win32com.client
catia_com = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('CATIA.Application')

# then later when needed, do some pywinauto stuff
import pywinauto.application

# back to working directly on catia com object
print(catia.caption)  # it works!
```

## Cause and explanation (as best as I could determine)

#### TLDR

`import comtypes` calls `CoInitializeEx` with flag `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` which happens to override the mode set by `win32com.client.GetActiveObject`.

#### Full explanation

I came to this conclusion because when commenting out `pythoncom.CoUninitialize()` (I was worried that it was killing the COM object returned from `win32com.client.GetActiveObject`) in `pywinauto.__init__` and reruning the code the following error was raised from `comtypes.__init__`:

```
OSError: [WinError -2147417850] Cannot change thread mode after it is set
```

I know that `comtypes.__init__` handels choosing the default flags for `CoInitializeEx` and couldn't deduce how the `win32com` lib is but figures it is also probably checking for existing flags, so I added `import comtypes`.

#### Where I'm still fuzzy

1. How do you determine what the concurrency model flags are for win32com?
2. How do you specify the concurrency model flags when calling win32com.client.GetActiveObject?
3. Why exactly does the solution work... calling `pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(0x0)` right before calling win32com.client.GetActiveObject doesn't work!

If I can get the above answered I can make a recommendation to win32com to set `sys.coinit_flags` (this is where `comtypes.__init__` is checking).

## Rescources

- https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objbase/ne-objbase-tagcoinit
- http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/pythoncom.html
- Not sure what the best win32com documentation is!